# Using a variable as part of a javascript object property

Tags: javascript

Another very simple question.

I have some code like this:

```
var a = {"foo":"bar"};
```

Which creates an object called `a` with a property called `foo` with value `bar`.

I'd like to do this:

```
var propName = "foo";
a = {propName:"bar"};
```

And for the two `a` objects to be the same.

How do I do that?

(Context is that I'm building an object to pass to jQuery's css method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set it in two steps:

```
var a = {};
a[propName] = 'bar';
```